# Vuetify Datatable search with expand

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I am gradually learning about vuetify tables, and learning a lot but I cannot figure out how to make search work with the code below.

I have followed [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/data-and-display/#search)

I have found that if i add any term to the search then make a change to my code when i return to my app the search filter is applied

I have the following

```
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :search="search"
    :sort-by="[{ key: 'calories', order: 'asc' }]"
    item-value="name"
    show-expand
>

    <template v-slot:top>

            <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
                density="compact"
                label="Search"
                single-line
                flat
                hide-details
                variant="solo-filled"

            ></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
    </template>

<template v-slot:item="{item, internalItem, isExpanded, toggleExpand}">
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    ... 
    <td @click="toggleExpand(internalItem)"><v-btn :icon="isExpanded(internalItem) ? 'mdi-chevron-up' : 'mdi-chevron-down'" variant="plain"></v-btn></td>
</tr>
</template>

<template #expanded-row="{item, columns}">
  ...
</template>

</v-data-table>
```

Comment: What is relevant about the code provided?  Please review [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You mention multiple bits of code **not** shown in your question that sounds much more relevant.  `:search` prop, `search` variable, `v-slot:top`... It'd be prudent to include this code, and any other relevant code and information (where is the search field? what are your search terms? what is the actual data being searched? etc.)

Comment: Thanks Yoduh, Still very new to coding so appreciate the guidance, hopefully the edit above is clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I was not thinking about this correctly, after a lot of reading i changed the approach. This works for vuetify 3 and Nuxt 3 for search and expand

```
<template>
    <v-card
      flat
      title="Nutrition"
    >
      <template v-slot:text>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          label="Search"
          prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
          single-line
          variant="outlined"
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
  
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        :search="search"
        v-model="expanded"
        item-value="name"
        show-expand
      >
    
    <template v-slot:item.calories="{ value }">
        <v-chip :color="getColor(value)">
          {{ value }}
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    
      <template #expanded-row="{item, columns}">
          <tr>
            <td :colspan="columns.length">Item: {{item.name}} </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
    
    </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </template>
      


      <script>
      export default {
        data () {
          return {
            search: '',
            expanded: [],
            headers: [
              {
                align: 'start',
                key: 'name',
                sortable: false,
                title: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
              },
              { key: 'calories', title: 'Calories' },
              { key: 'fat', title: 'Fat (g)' },
              { key: 'carbs', title: 'Carbs (g)' },
              { key: 'protein', title: 'Protein (g)' },
              { key: 'iron', title: 'Iron (%)' },
            ],
            desserts: [
              {
                name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
                calories: 159,
                fat: 6.0,
                carbs: 24,
                protein: 4.0,
                iron: 1,
              },
              {
                name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
                calories: 237,
                fat: 9.0,
                carbs: 37,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: 1,
              },
              {
                name: 'Eclair',
                calories: 262,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 23,
                protein: 6.0,
                iron: 7,
              },
              {
                name: 'Cupcake',
                calories: 305,
                fat: 3.7,
                carbs: 67,
                protein: 4.3,
                iron: 8,
              },
              {
                name: 'Gingerbread',
                calories: 356,
                fat: 16.0,
                carbs: 49,
                protein: 3.9,
                iron: 16,
              },
              {
                name: 'Jelly bean',
                calories: 375,
                fat: 0.0,
                carbs: 94,
                protein: 0.0,
                iron: 0,
              },
              {
                name: 'Lollipop',
                calories: 392,
                fat: 0.2,
                carbs: 98,
                protein: 0,
                iron: 2,
              },
              {
                name: 'Honeycomb',
                calories: 408,
                fat: 3.2,
                carbs: 87,
                protein: 6.5,
                iron: 45,
              },
              {
                name: 'Donut',
                calories: 452,
                fat: 25.0,
                carbs: 51,
                protein: 4.9,
                iron: 22,
              },
              {
                name: 'KitKat',
                calories: 518,
                fat: 26.0,
                carbs: 65,
                protein: 7,
                iron: 6,
              },
            ],
          }
        },
          methods: {
    getColor (calories) {
      if (calories > 400) return 'red'
      else if (calories > 300) return 'orange'
      else return 'green'
    },
  },
      }
</script>
```